# Clear browser cache in laravel

Tags: php, caching, laravel-4

I'm developing an application with Laravel 4.2. I have not configured cache and cache settings are default. I have a two step sign up form. After, submitting the second form successfully, I redirect to success page. But when I click on back button of browser, it takes me to second step form and all the data is pre filled. I tried adding following code to header -

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

And following code, after registration in complete (in controller function)-

```
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

But it did not work. I tried to set a filter with above code and call it after register controller function. I also tried following code, but it also didn't work.

```
Cache::flush()
```

How can I clear the form, when reached using back button of browser ?

Comment: You tried `Input::clear();` ?

Comment: have you got your answer?? I have same problem...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068359/how-to-force-clean-browser-cache-laravel