# How to force clean browser cache laravel

Tags: php, laravel, caching, browser

Im new in web development. I just want to ask if how to force clean all cache in the browser using **PHP**.

Comment: Simply, You can't.

Answer (score 4):

The best you can do is set a cache-control header, but you cannot "force" anything on client with a server-side language.

In laravel:

```
return view('some_template')->header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0');
```

In plain php you would use header() function before outputting anything.

```
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0');
```

Comment: I'm getting error like below "BadMethodCallException in View.php line 394: Method [header] does not exist on view."

Comment: Can't you clear the browser using the Vue part of the Laravel app?

Comment: For those who get the error - `view::header does not exist`, you can use the following format - `return response()->view('some_template')->header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0');`

Answer (score 1):

PHP is on server side. You have no control over browsers.

Comment: As above, you can't control it but you can certainly *ask* it to avoid caching a page.